# How can I record my app video and have mouse pointer show as white circle

Tags: iphone, video, video-streaming, screen-recording

Hello I want to record my app video like this. specifically I like the mouse pointer icon. I have tried to record the app from quicktime but it shows my mouse general icon, not white circle icon like the video

https://s3.amazonaws.com/fueled-com/assets/video/quizup.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to `quick time player` -> `file` -> `New Screen Recording`

Then drag area which you want to record in your `desktop` and then recording starts.

If you want to stop recording then right click on  `quick time player` select stop recording.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already mentioned that yes I have tried to record it in quicktime but I it shows the regular cursor in the video not like the video I shared

Comment: you can not change style of your cursor in mac you can only change size of your cursor if you want.